# Prompting user when application closes

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am making a web browser for the windows phone platform, and I am using the back button as an a navigation back key for the browser. However, windows phone requires the back button to also close the app or close it by prompting the user. I myself am trying this, though I just can't get it to work together. Here's my code

```
 if (webTab1.Margin == new Thickness())
 {
    try
    {
        webTab1.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBoxResult mb = MessageBox.Show("You want exit the page", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        if (mb != MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
 }
```

i need it so if the backbutton is pressed and the browser doesnt navigate it should prompt the user to close the app.

Answer (score 0):

Using JS isn't the most reliable way to do this.

If you're using WP8 you can query the `WebBrowser` to check if it has other pages on the browser history to navigate back to.

```
if (webTab1.Margin == new Thickness())
{
    if (webTab1.CanGoBack)
    {
        webTab1.GoBack();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBoxResult mb = MessageBox.Show("You want exit the page", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        if (mb != MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        } 
    }
}
```

However this isn't available on WP7.

Comment: thanks, do you know the assembly reference i have to add o make it work?

Comment: `CanGoBack` and `GoBack` are both member methods of WebBrowser (I'm assuming that `webTab1` is a WebBrowser as it's not clear). You don't need to change the references.

Comment: yeah, webTab1 is a webbrowser although the goback and cangoback doesnt work?